# $f(\overline{x})=0$ but $\nabla^2 f(\overline{x})$ is not semidefinite positive. Prove there exists a descent direction

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, maxima-minima

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}, f\in C^2,
>  \overline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\nabla f(\overline{x})=0$ but
>   $\nabla^2 f(\overline{x})$ is not semidefinite positive. Prove that
>   there exists a descent direction $d$ in $\overline{x}$

I think that the following theorem helps solving the exercise:

> Theorem: let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}, f\in C^2$. If $x^*$ is a
>   local minizer of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$ and
>    $\nabla^2 f(x^*)$ is semidefinite positive

So, since **$x^*$ local minimizer $\implies$ $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$ and $\nabla^2 f(x^*)$ is semidefinite positive**, the contrapositive in this case is that since **$\nabla^2 f(x^*)$ is not semidefinite positive, we have that $x^*$ is not a local minimizer**. Therefore, there exists a ball around $x^*$ such that for $x$ in the ball, $f(x)<f(x^*)$. Since it's a ball, we can pick any direction $d$ inside this ball, starting from $x^*$ such that $x^*+\lambda d$ is still in the ball. It's just a matter of picking the right $\lambda$. Therefore there exists a descent direction $d$

---

**Second proof attempt:**

$$f(x+p) = f(x) + p^t\nabla f(x) + \frac{1}{2}p^t\nabla^2f(x+tp)p$$

for some $t\in (0,1)$ by taylor's theorem.

We know that $h^t\nabla^2f(x+rh)h<0$ for small $r$. By the taylor expansion:

$$f(x+rp) = f(x) + rp^t\nabla f(x) + \frac{1}{2}rp^t\nabla^2f(x+rtp)rp$$

for $t\in(0,1)$.

Then by doing $\overline{t} = rt$:

$$f(x+rp) = f(x) + rp^t\nabla f(x) + \frac{1}{2}r^2p^t\nabla^2f(x+\overline{t}p)p$$

for $\overline{t}\in(0,r)$.

We end up with:

$$f(x+rp) = f(x) + \frac{1}{2}r^2p^t\nabla^2f(x+\overline{t}p)p$$

but the last term is negative by what I said in the beggining. Therefore, $f(x+rp)<f(x)$ for small $r$, so $p$ is our descent direction.

Comment: Hint (which should be liberally applied in proving optimzation results): use Taylor's theorem

Comment: @mheldman but is there a problem with my proof?

Comment: Yeah, so it's not true that if $x$ is not a local minimizer then there exists a ball $B_\epsilon(x^*)$ around $x^*$ such that $f(x) < f(x^*)$ for all $x\in B_\epsilon(x^*)$. It is true that if $x^*$ is not a local minimizer then there exists a sequence $(x_n) \to x^*$ such that $f(x_n) < f(x^*)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But this doesn't really help you prove that there is a descent direction. I stick by my original suggestion: use Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: You're right. $x^*$ is not a local minimizer, then for every ball around $x^*$, there's always a point $\overline{x}$ such that $f(\overline{x})<f(x^*)$. Therefore I can always pick the direction $x^* + 1\cdot(\overline{x}-x^*)$. Is this rigth? If I were to use the Taylor Theorem, then I'd to $f(x + p) = f(x) + p^t\nabla f(x) + p^t\nabla^2 f(x+tp)p$ for some $t\in (0,1)$. Therefore, $\nabla^2f$ being not semipositivedef. means there's $x$ such that $x\nabla^2fx<0$. But I don't see how this influences $p^t\nabla^2 f(x+tp)p$

Comment: A descent direction would be a vector $d$ for which $f(x + td) < f(x)$ for all $t$ sufficiently small, which is why I think the local minimizer argument fails. To use Taylor's Theorem, assume WLOG that $x = 0$. Then we have $f(td) = t^2d^T\nabla^2 f(sd)d$ for all $d\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $t\in [0,1]$, and some $s\in [0,1]$. You've gotten this far on your own. Now try to use continuity of $\nabla^2 f$ and the fact that there exists $d\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $d^T\nabla^2 f(0)d < 0$ (i.e. $\nabla^2 f(0)$ is negative semi-definite).

Comment: Note that not being a local minimiser is not the same as having a descent direction.

Comment: The only thing missing in your proof is to show that $p^t\nabla^2f(x+\overline{t}p)p $ is locally bounded  above by some negative number. That is where the $-\delta$ comes from in the answer below.

Comment: @copper.hat why is that needed? I showed that for small $r$ we have the second order term negative. Shouldn't this be sufficient for $p$ to be a descent direction?

Comment: Like I said, the proof is roughly correct, but you are missing some formalities. You have not justified why the term is negative. See my proof, it is the first thing I did.

Comment: @copper.hat oh ok. I wrote 'we know that $h^t\cdots<0$ for small $r$, thinking about continuity but I didn't write it explicitly. Is it what you mean? Since $\nabla^2$ is continuous, there's an interval where $h^t\nabla^2h$ is still negative.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: Yes, that is what meant. Personally, I like to nail down the details to some level. Sometimes the extra detail gives a little extra insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is not positive semi definite, then there is some $h$ such that
$h^TAh < 0$.

This is an application of Taylor's theorem and continuity.

By continuity of the Hessian $H(x)$ we see that there is some neighbourhood of $\bar{x}$ such that $h^T H(x) h < -\delta = {1 \over 2} h^T H(\bar{x}) h$.

Let $\phi(t) = f(\bar{x}+th)$, then Taylor gives
$\phi(t) = \phi(0)+ \phi'(0) t + {1 \over 2} \phi''(\xi) t^2$ for some $\xi \in (0,t)$.

Since $\phi'(0) = 0, \phi''(\xi) = h^T H(\bar{x}+ \xi h) h$, we see that
$f(x+th) \le f(x) - {1 \over 2} \delta t^2$ for small $t$.

Note that both $h$ and $-h$ are descent directions.

The integral form of the theorem gives an explicit formula, but is messier to type :-).

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you did. Why $\le$ sign? Why $-\delta$ in the name of the variable?

Comment: I don't really understand either of your questions. What $\le$? I am just defining $\delta = - {1 \over 2} h^T H(\bar{x}) h$.

Comment: Normally you'd end the proof saying $f(x+th) = f(x) + \mbox{ something negative }$ and therefore $f(x+th)<f(x)$, but you did something I don't understand: $f(x+th)\le f(x)-\frac{1}{2}\delta t^2$

Comment: How can $h^T H(x) h < -\delta = {1 \over 2} h^T H(\bar{x}) h$? Why one has $1/2$ and the other not?

Comment: Could you take a look at my update in the answer? I did a second proof attempt based on yours

Comment: One has $\bar{x}$, the other is a nearby $x$. Your proof is roughly right, but your estimate of the second order term needs to be corrected. Unfortunately I am not near a laptop so explaining is a pain.